# regex for splitting a string based on everything except certain characters

Tags: ruby, regex, string, split

I want to split a string based on all aphabets and other spl characters except digits ,/ ,\ ,(  ,) and comma.

i tried this regex . `s.split( /^[\d\,\\\/\+\(\)]/)`

sample string: `hi my% num is +91 67 (987)92471/72,73`
I want this separated as `["hi my " ,"num is","+91 67 (987)92471/72,73 ]`

Comment: i am unclear how you want to split this. What are you supposed to split on to get "hi my num"  and "is" separately? It's not whitespace, because then "hi my mum" would be separated.

Comment: Your desired output shows that you want your string split on a space between 'num' and 'is' due to that space being special in some way and also strip out the % sign?

Comment: my bad. ive updated the post now.

Comment: basically i want a regex to split based on all chars except digits commas and /,\, +,(,)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, this is probably what you are looking for

```
>>> import re
>>> s='hi my% num is +91 67 (987)92471/72,73'
>>> re.split(r'[^a-zA-Z \d,\\/()]', s)
['hi my', ' num is ', '91 67 (987)92471/72,73']
```

- [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) doesn't accept regular expressions
- `[^a-zA-Z \d,\\/()]` means any character other than alphabets, space, digits, comma, backslash, forward slash, and parentheses
- for the given input string, the `%` and `+` characters created the splits. Modify the regex as needed